# Phonetic IPA sounds problem to transfer to ePub format

Tags: fonts, formatting

I have the problem to transfer text with IPA symbols without losing them to ePub format. After formatting as ePub the symbols are not present. See the images: [image: proper fonts in pdf file] the others are just normal fonts and not identified ones [image: fonts not visible in ePub]
Is there a way for that to work?
Should I use different IPA font in original file? Now I use SilDouos ipa9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try to embed a different font. Free fonts with good IPA coverage are:

[Charis SIL](https://software.sil.org/charis/download/)

[Source Sans Pro](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-sans-pro)

If embedding a different font didn't solve your problem, it was most likely caused by the epub converter that you used.
What's the source file format and what tool did you use to convert it to an epub file?

Comment: It was exported in InDesign.

Comment: Did embedding a different font solve your problem?


 If not post the HTML source code that you used for the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks it helped. But had to change each word manually.